# How do I query within the ELSE of a CASE WHEN?

Tags: mysql, case

My current query works just fine outside of the CASE WHEN:

```
select *, timestampdiff(DAY, from_unixtime(laststaffreplytime, '%Y-%m-%d'), 
curdate()) from swtickets;
```

However, when this is placed in the ELSE of a CASE WHEN, the column produces all null values:

```
SELECT *, CASE laststaffreplytime
WHEN 0 THEN 'No Response' 
ELSE (timestampdiff(DAY, from_unixtime(laststaffreplytime, '%Y-%m-%d'), 
curdate())) END as LastContact from swtickets;
```

Any ideas as to why this query is returning only null values?

Comment: Additionally, the CASE performs successfully if I replace the timestampdiff query with 'responded'

Comment: And using `DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), FROM_UNIXTIME(laststaffreplytime))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CASE operator has to be able to return a single data type -- your sample returns a string in one case, and an integer in the other. I don't *think* that should turn the results into NULLs -- I would expect that the integers would be represented as strings in that case -- but anything's possible with MySQL :)

Try changing the "No Response" to a fixed integer value, like -1, to see if that changes the results.

From the manual:

> The return type of a CASE expression is the compatible aggregated type of all return values, but also depends on the context in which it is used. If used in a string context, the result is returned as a string. If used in a numeric context, the result is returned as a decimal, real, or integer value.

Comment: Perfect- changing the string to an integer worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, CASE laststaffreplytime
WHEN '0' THEN 'No Response' 
ELSE (timestampdiff(DAY, from_unixtime(laststaffreplytime, '%Y-%m-%d'), 
curdate())) END as LastContact from swtickets;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this gives me the same result.